# ActiveModelSerializers camelCase transform when don't have serializer class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I found a way to transform object keys from `snake_case` to `camelCase` in rails with the ActiveModelSerializers gem

`# config/initializers/ams_config.rb
ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :camel_lower`

The problem is that for some models I don't create a Serializer class (a class that inherits from ActiveModel::Serializer) but just call in my controller to
`render json: @some_resource` or even `render json: {my_key: value}`

I want these objects to get transformed to camelCase as well.

How do I make ActiveModelSerializers to be the default serializer which serializes any object I render as `:json` ?

Comment: Why not have serializers for the methods you want to serialize?

Comment: Sometimes I am serializing objects on the fly like render json: {a: 1, b: 2} and sometimes I want to serialize a while model without the need to create a serializer for it and copy all attributes to the serializer class

Comment: Doing that happens completely outside of the realm of ActiveModelSerializers, you are basically skipping them. Couldn't you simply camelize the properties then. `render json: { myKey: value }`

Comment: with the hash example { myKey: value } I can but when it is an object i can't (unless I add code that go through all keys and camelCase them) I prefere a solution where I make all my render json to work with the activemodelserializers which deep transform keeys for me